# ExpressJs : Safe To Use Reserved Word DELETE as method name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Delete is one of the reserved words in JavaScript however ExpressJS uses it as a method name. Their [Basic Routing](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html) documentation shows:

> `app.METHOD(PATH, HANDLER)`
>
> Where:
>
> app is an instance of express. METHOD is an HTTP request method, in
> lowercase. PATH is a path on the server. HANDLER is the function
> executed when the route is matched.

And what I would like to do is export a delete method for my router, e.g. `router.delete('/api/v1/:id', handler.delete);` however I don't want to further violate the language. Would it be bad practice to export a `module.exports.delete = deleteHandler`?

Comment: There are no problems with `.delete()` as a property/method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete` is only a keyword in specific contexts, it can sometimes be used as an identifier like `for` can.

[image: assigning for as a property of an object foo]

If the word `delete` makes sense to you, and it is consistent with other things you've done, then there isn't anything wrong with it.